# Vue.js Getting erros even if component is not rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component that only renders if there is data to show.

```
<v-row v-if="openPositions.length !== 0" justify="center" align="end" class="mt-1">
```

This works perfectly.

However, even when this component is not rendered, error messages are printed, because some data is undefined within this component, but that's why I'm not displaying the table in the first place.

How can I stop these error messages?

===== EDIT =====

Below you can see the complete component code and below that the error from the console.

```
<template>
  <v-row v-if="openPositions.length" justify="center" align="end" class="mt-1">
    <v-col sm="12">
      <v-data-table
      
        v-if="this.full"
        dense
        align="center"
        :headers="headers_full"
        :items="openPositions"
        hide-default-footer
      >
        <template v-slot:item.symbol="{ item }">
          <span>{{ item.symbol }}</span>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item.size="{ item }">
          <span v-if="item.side === 'sell'" class="error--text">{{
            item.size
          }}</span>

          <span v-if="item.side === 'buy'" class="success--text">{{
            item.size
          }}</span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.position_value="{ item }">
          <span>
            {{ item.position_value.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.entry_price="{ item }">
          <span>
            {{ item.entry_price.toFixed(2) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.liq_price="{ item }">
          <span>
            {{ item.liq_price.toFixed(2) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.position_margin="{ item }">
          <span>
            {{ item.position_margin.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.unrealised_pnl_last="{ item }">
          <span v-if="item.unrealised_pnl_last < 0" class="error--text">
            {{ item.unrealised_pnl_last.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else-if="item.unrealised_pnl_last > 0" class="success--text">
            {{ item.unrealised_pnl_last.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else>
            {{ item.unrealised_pnl_last.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.realised_pnl="{ item }">
          <span v-if="item.realised_pnl < 0" class="error--text">
            {{ item.realised_pnl.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else-if="item.realised_pnl > 0" class="success--text">
            {{ item.realised_pnl.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else>
            {{ item.realised_pnl.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.daily_total="{ item }">
          <span v-if="item.daily_total < 0" class="error--text">
            {{ item.daily_total.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else-if="item.daily_total > 0" class="success--text">
            {{ item.daily_total.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else>
            {{ item.daily_total.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.market_close="{ item }">
          <v-btn x-small color="primary" @click="marketClose(item)">
            Close
          </v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
      <v-data-table
        v-else
        dense
        align="center"
        :headers="headers_reduced"
        :items="openPositions"
        hide-default-footer
      >
        <template v-slot:item.symbol="{ item }">
          <span>{{ item.symbol }}</span>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:item.size="{ item }">
          <span v-if="item.side === 'sell'" class="error--text">{{
            item.size
          }}</span>

          <span v-if="item.side === 'buy'" class="success--text">{{
            item.size
          }}</span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.position_value="{ item }">
          <span>
            {{ item.position_value.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.entry_price="{ item }">
          <span>
            {{ item.entry_price.toFixed(2) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.liq_price="{ item }">
          <span>
            {{ item.liq_price.toFixed(2) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.position_margin="{ item }">
          <span>
            {{ item.position_margin.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.unrealised_pnl_last="{ item }">
          <span v-if="item.unrealised_pnl_last < 0" class="error--text">
            {{ item.unrealised_pnl_last.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else-if="item.unrealised_pnl_last > 0" class="success--text">
            {{ item.unrealised_pnl_last.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else>
            {{ item.unrealised_pnl_last.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.realised_pnl="{ item }">
          <span v-if="item.realised_pnl < 0" class="error--text">
            {{ item.realised_pnl.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else-if="item.realised_pnl > 0" class="success--text">
            {{ item.realised_pnl.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else>
            {{ item.realised_pnl.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.daily_total="{ item }">
          <span v-if="item.daily_total < 0" class="error--text">
            {{ item.daily_total.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else-if="item.daily_total > 0" class="success--text">
            {{ item.daily_total.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
          <span v-else>
            {{ item.daily_total.toFixed(6) }}
          </span>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:item.market_close="{ item }">
          <v-btn x-small color="primary" @click="marketClose(item)">
            Close
          </v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script>
import store from "../store";
export default {
  store,
  name: "OpenPositions",
  components: {},
  props: [],
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      headers_full: [
        { text: "Open Position", value: "symbol" },
        { text: "Qty", value: "size" },
        { text: "Value", value: "position_value" },
        { text: "Price", value: "entry_price" },
        { text: "Liq. Price", value: "liq_price" },
        { text: "Margin", value: "position_margin" },
        { text: "Leverage", value: "leverage" },
        {
          text: "Unrealized P&L",
          value: "unrealised_pnl_last",
        },
        { text: "Daily Realized P&L", value: "realised_pnl" },
        { text: "Daily Total (% of Account)", value: "daily_total" },
        { text: "SL", value: "stop_loss" },
        { text: "TP", value: "take_profit" },
        { text: "TS", value: "trailing_stop" },
        { text: "Stops", value: "trading_stops" },
        { text: "Market close", value: "market_close" },
      ],
      headers_reduced: [
        { text: "Open Position", value: "symbol" },
        { text: "Qty", value: "size" },
        { text: "Value", value: "position_value" },
        { text: "Price", value: "entry_price" },
        { text: "Liq. Price", value: "liq_price" },
        { text: "Margin", value: "position_margin" },
        { text: "Leverage", value: "leverage" },
        {
          text: "Unrealized P&L",
          value: "unrealised_pnl_last",
        },
        { text: "Daily Realized P&L", value: "realised_pnl" },
        { text: "Daily Total (% of Account)", value: "daily_total" },
        { text: "Market close", value: "market_close" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async marketClose(item) {
      await this.$apiAbstraction.marketOrder(
        item.symbol,
        item.side === "buy" ? "sell" : "buy",
        Math.abs(item.size)
      );
    },
  },
  computed: {
    openPositions() {
      return store.getters.getOpenPositionsByExchange(
        store.getters.getExchange
      );
    },
    full() {
      return store.getters.getExchange !== "deribit";
    },
  },
  mounted() {},
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

The error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: item.position_value.toFixed is not a function"

found in

---> <VData>
       <VDataTable>
         <OpenPositions> at src/components/OpenPositions.vue
           <Ladder> at src/views/Ladder.vue
             <VMain>
               <VApp>
                 <App> at src/App.vue
                   <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3550
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4066
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4479
run @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4554
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4310
eval @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980
flushCallbacks @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1933
nextTick @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1990
queueWatcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4402
update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4544
notify @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730
reactiveSetter @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055
setOpenPositions @ exchanges.js?d86e:169
wrappedMutationHandler @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:840
commitIterator @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:462
eval @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:461
_withCommit @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:620
commit @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:460
boundCommit @ vuex.esm.js?2f62:405
handleOnMessage @ deribitApi.js?89c3:141
_this.ws.onmessage @ deribitApi.js?89c3:59
ReconnectingWebSocket._handleMessage @ reconnecting-websocket-mjs.js?d096:172
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: item.position_value.toFixed is not a function
    at fn (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"7c63af54-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/OpenPositions.vue?vue&type=template&id=3ad75d40&scoped=true& (app.js:1010), <anonymous>:279:64)
    at normalized (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2590)
    at eval (Row.ts?6e51:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at render (Row.ts?6e51:22)
    at createFunctionalComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3058)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3231)
    at _createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3434)
    at createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3353)
    at VueComponent.vm.$createElement (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3494)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of errors you are getting? :)

Comment: I think you have to judge whether there is data before loading the first screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit (after seeing the actual error):

The problem is you're trying to use `.toFixed` on something that is not a number. To guard against it, you have to wrap the value in `Number`.

```
Number(item.daily_total || 0).toFixed(6)
```

Also, your `item.daily-total` template slot can be significantly simplified as:

```
<template v-slot:item.daily_total="{ value }">
  <span :class="{ 'error--text': value < 0, 'success--text': value > 0 }"
        v-text="Number(value || 0).toFixed(6)" />
</template>
```

Obviously, you should use a similar approach to the other templates as well.

Because you use it in more than one place, you could DRY your code up and use a Vue component to apply the success/error classes:

```
<template>
  <span :class="cellClass"
         v-text="Number(value || 0).toFixed(toFixed || 2)" />
</template>
<script>
  export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'CellValue',
    props: ['value', 'item', 'header', 'toFixed'],
    computed: {
      cellClass() {
        return {
          'error--text': this.value < 0,
          'success--text': this.value > 0
        }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

...import it as a Vue component and use it in your table templates as:

```
<template v-slot:item.daily_total="cell">
  <cell-value v-bind="cell" :to-fixed="6" />
</template>
```

You don't need to declare `item` or `header` as props, but they're provided by the Vuetify slot, in case you need them.
Note I also added an extra `prop` called `to-fixed`, defaulting to `2` which determines the number of decimals. You could rename it `decimals`.
Also note I default the `value` to `0` to avoid any errors around using `.toFixed()` on anything that's not of type `number`.
If, for example, you prefer to display a custom text when the value is of any other type than `number`, you could use something more elaborate in `CellValue`'s template:

```
<template>
  <span :class="cellClass">
    <template v-if="typeof value === 'number'">
      {{ value.toFixed(toFixed || 2) }}
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <code>{{ value || '--' }}</code>
    </template>
  </span>
</template>
```

---

For reference, I'm leaving here the initial answer, as it might help others:

Whenever your template depends on an expression which errors in some cases because it tries to access properties/methods of `undefined` entities, the easiest workaround is to create a `computed` property which avoids the exception:

`<template>`:

```
<v-row v-if="hasOpenPositions" justify="center" align="end" class="mt-1">
```

`<script>`:

```
computed: {
  hasOpenPositions() {
    return this.openPositions && this.openPositions.length !== 0;
  }
}
```

However, be warned the above computed will return `true` when `openPositions` is truthy and it doesn't have a `length` property (when its `length` is `undefined`;  i.e.: `openPositions: {}` - because `undefined !== 0`).

Another slightly shorter syntax I find myself using is:

```
computed: {
  hasOpenPositions() {
    return !!(this.openPositions?.length);
  }
}
```

(This one only returns `true` when `openPositions` has a truthy `length`, which is probably what you want).

Do note [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`) does not work in `<template>`, at least for now.

---

The above is a general workaround which comes in handy with deep objects, so your template doesn't error when the objects have not yet been populated/loaded.

However, if `openPositions` is an array, you should just instantiate it as an empty array and simplify your check as:

`<template>`:

```
<v-row v-if="openPositions.length" justify="center" align="end" class="mt-1">
```

`<script>`:

```
data: () => ({
  openPositions: []
}),
mounted() {
  this.$http.get('some/api').then(r => { this.openPositions = r.data })
}
```

The relevant bit here is `openPositions` is an array at all times (so it always has a `length` internal method) and that it's reactive. How you update it (in `mounted` or some method) is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the error is not generated in openPositions. I'm updating the original question with some more code and the error. Maybe that might help analysing this.

Comment: @MPL, a [mcve] would be ideal. *"...some data is undefined within this component"* really doesn't give any debugging info. That's why I tried to explain the principle, so you could apply it to other cases in your component(s).

Comment: I've added the component itself and the error on the console. I hope that helps. Thanks for staying on this!!!

Comment: The problem is you're trying to use `.toFixed` on something that is not a number. To guard against it, you have to wrap the value in `Number`. For example: `Number(item.daily_total || 0).toFixed(6)`.

Comment: we're getting closer. The 'simple' parts are now working, but the cells where I change the font colour based on the value are not, e.g         
          <span v-if="Number(item.unrealised_pnl_last || 0) < 0" class="error--text">

Comment: bit now when I look at it, it seems as if <v-row v-if="openPositions.length" justify="center" align="end" class="mt-1"> is rendering regardless of openPositions.length check. 
After adding the changes you proposed the table got rendered, but with 0.000 in the number fields

Comment: I'm certain `openPositions.length` is truthy if it renders. You can output it in your template, (outside of the table: `{{openPositions.length}}` ) to make sure. I can assure you Vue works as expected. :). Also note the scope of this answer is not to help you solve a series of errors and finalize some functionality, but rather to help you (and anyone with the same error) solve this particular one. If you need assistance or guidance finalizing your project (a solve all errors approach) you either ask a single question for each type of error, if you can't find it answered, or look elsewhere.

Comment: Actually the core of my problem is solved, in the sense that I was assuming that javascript is not evaluated if the template containing it is not rendered, that is clearly not the case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218583/discussion-between-tao-and-mpl).